# Why sometimes finally is used for debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, exception, finally

I have read a lot of sources about debugging `try,exception,finally` . I do understand when we try some codes there are might be some exception. But I dont understand why sometimes we use finally when we already have exception?

Comment: `finally` is **always** executed. Sometimes code after `exception` may not get executed.. (Think about a situation that an exception is thrown *within* the `exception` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is indicated in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions), the `finally` clause is useful for releasing external resources, regardless of whether the use was successful. These external resources can be files or network connections, which require to be cleaned-up under all circumstances.

For instance:

```
try:
   f = open("testfile", "w")
   try:
      f.write("This may not work!")
   finally:
      f.close()
except IOError:
   print("Error! Can't find file")
```

The statement `f.close()` will always be executed, so even if the write operation raises an exception, the file will always be closed at the end.